# When scrolling how can I change the TEXT color of a floating header menu?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm building this site [www.shapeinthecity2.unicornrobots.com](http://shapeinthecity2.unicornrobots.com/) and I have a transparent floating header menu with white text on the homepage.

However, the text gets hidden as you scroll down. Is there a way to change the text color to black after you scroll past a certain point?

Below is the CSS script I've added so far,

Thanks

```css
/*--- Menu Spacing & Color ---*/

.home #header-right-menu li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.home #header-right-menu ul ul a {
    color: #cccccc;
}
#header-right-menu ul ul a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.top-navigation a, #header-right-menu a {
    color: #000000;
    margin-right: 80px;
}
#header-right-menu li a:hover {
    color: #ff6600;
}
.top-navigation a, #header-right-menu ul ul a {
    background: #000000;
}
.site-logo img {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
.home.transparent-header .site-header {
    position: fixed;
    top:50px;    
}
/*--- Menu Spacing & Color End ---*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am not able to see your floating header, may be your script not working. As your site have one error. Check your source.

your code is visible on the site:

```
$('#whitediv').waypoint(function() {
alert('Change your background color of div');
$('.navbar').css('background-color', '#000000');
}, {
offset: '5%'
});
```

This code is visible. Please check and correct. Then we can check it properly. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sunniya, thanks for having a look. I found a possible solution here http://jsfiddle.net/Trd7D/2/ but have no idea how to implement the javascipt into wordpress. I've taken the out now